# wordpress wp-config.php not getting updated when I deploy new version to gae

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine

wp-config.php doesn't seem to get updated, the DB_HOST holds the old value. Multiple deployment with a new version id and update value for DB_HOST doesn't seem to reflect. The wp-config.php file seem be cached in the GAE.

How can I force this file to be updated in the server ?. I added the following entry in app.yaml file, that doesn't seem to help either.

```
- url: .*
  script: wp-config.php
  secure: always
```

Comment: I got through that by just deleting all the version in the GAE and trying a new version today morning. Now I have the next error to resolve, db connection _**Error establishing a database connection** This either means that the username and password information in your wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can't contact the database server at :/cloudsql/vairagyawp:wordpress._  Here is my db connection details. _define('DB_HOST', ':/cloudsql/vairagyawp:wordpress');
        define('DB_USER', 'root');
        define('DB_PASSWORD', '');_ what could be the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

You might be using Varnish, try turning that off and on. Or for development purposes just keep Varnish off entirely.

Comment: No Varnish enabled. What I noticed in the appcfg.py upload log is, its referring to a wrong app-id **06:25 AM Application: vairagyawp (was: vairagyawordpress); version: 16 (was: 1)**.  **vairagyawp** is a new app, but it is referring to the app-id (**vairagyawordpress**) which I deleted a while ago.

Comment: I got this resolved, I again deleted and created a new app. It works and changes I make is also reflecting now. I have a new error **Error establishing a database connection**.  I went through the previous post, and ensured **DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, the cloudsql instance name is wordpress **. But still able to connect, any suggestion ?

Comment: If you created a new app, then I believe you have to either create a new sql instance or update the sql instance that was pointing to your old app because I think the sql instance includes your app id in the name or you do that in the config.php file